# Asexual Reproduction Of sponges through endogenous or exogenous budding?

Tags: zoology, physiology, reproduction

I was studying asexual reproduction in sponges and came across *two website*

1. [Wikipedia of Gemmule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gemmule) and there is a line....

> **Only Endogenous Types of Buds** develop into *New Sponges*.

Then as I was reading this Website [Sponges](https://www.biologydiscussion.com/invertebrate-zoology/sponges/sponges-characters-classification-and-types-zoology/28518) there is a Section **9.1. iii) Budding**, in which, there is Two Parts i.e **(a) Exogenous Budding** and **(b) Endogenous Budding**

So now, I am a bit confused..... if only Endogenous Bud can give rise to New Sponges *then why* there is a section of exogenous budding i.e reproducing through exogenous buds,in the reproduction section of sponges, in this website [sponges](https://www.biologydiscussion.com/invertebrate-zoology/sponges/sponges-characters-classification-and-types-zoology/28518) ? **ISN'T that Contradiction**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that the quoted sentence from the [Wikipedia gemmule article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gemmule) is wrong.  The first sentence of the containing paragraph says:

> Asexual reproduction in sponges occurs via budding, either by external or internal buds.

At face value, the two sentences together imply that sponges can reproduce by external budding, but that the external budding "reproduction" does not produce "new sponges"(!). Note that the most recent [edit to the article (on 10 March)](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Gemmule&diff=prev&oldid=944869791) was by an anonymous user who changed the sentence you quoted from "Both types" to "Only endogenous types", so this was a somewhat recent corruption.